# Shadow Photo Viewer - Center viewed photo on screen in iframe

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, lightbox, thumbnails

I have a thumbnail gallery that expands an iframe so there is no scroll bar on the iframe itself. when a user clicks a thumbnail a div is shown that covers the entire iframe with a transparent grey and displays the fullsize image in the center. Similar to the facebook lightbox.

I want the full size image to scroll when the user scrolls the page, so that when they click on a thumbnail lower down the page it is displayed in the center of the screen and not at the top of the page.

Comment: Please see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for how to ask questions. Maybe show us some of your code you're having issues with, not just ask for us to write you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `postion:fixed;` on the lightbox.